# How to make secure service to service communication in istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to call a web service running in another pod from one pod in istio.

I wrote both micro-services in python. Could you please tell how to make https call from one micro service running in one pod to another micro service running in another pod.

I can find the below sample command from istio web site.

```
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c istio-proxy -- curl https://httpbin:8000/headers -o /dev/null -s -w '%{http_code}\n' --key /etc/certs/key.pem --cert /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem --cacert /etc/certs/root-cert.pem -k
```

But that is making https call from istio-proxy container, but how my microservice will forward the request to istio-proxy which then forwards the request to another istio-proxy in different pod?

From this link https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/, I cannot understand statement 'Istio re-routes the outbound traffic from a client to the client’s local sidecar Envoy.'? What is the code change in my python microservice to call https web service? Please give full example if you have any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [task](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/https-overlay/) from istio docs shows how mutual TLS works with HTTPS services. It includes:

- Deploying an HTTPS service without Istio sidecar
- Deploying an HTTPS service with Istio with mutual TLS disabled
- Deploying an HTTPS service with mutual TLS enabled.

All of the above scenarios provides command that you can run on one microservice container to hit https endpoint of another micro service. For example to hit nginx over https from the sleep container

```
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- curl https://my-nginx -k
```

The benefit of istio is that you don't need to do any code change in your python application. Istio proxy side car will do necessary stuff to enable the security features such as mTLS.

Comment: We are generating the certificates using openssl and providing to nginx-app, but how the sleep service will get certificates to make https request?

Comment: You need to store the certificate in a secret and volume mount that secret in sleep service.

Comment: Is this the correct way to call from client (sleep) . Its a python code.

**r = requests.get('https://myservice2/service2', auth=None, cert='cert.pem', verify=False)**

I will create a secret for cert.pem for client pod

Comment: What happens if you just call that https nginx service from your python app without providing it a certificate? the istio sidecar should take care of security automatically from the secret that you have mounted

Comment: I provided certificate and then it worked, thank you